# Solid colorize visible pixels of image

Tags: image, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I have a picture like Source:

[image: img].

My goal is to display it like Result:

[image: img].

The color must be variable.

Is it possible to do that using `glEnable/glBlendFunc/glBlendFuncSeparate/glBlendEquationSeparate`?

Or do I have to use a shader (glsl)? How would this shader look like?

Comment: in GLSL it would be simple fragment shader, in GL you need first create a mask from your image (on your own not with GL which is also simple 2 nested `for`s and one `if`) and then use simple `glColor` ...

Comment: Seems overkill to use Open Gl ES only for that. Unless you want to change the color at every frame, I would recommand to load your image in a Bitmap object, and use getPixels() / setPixels() to alter it the way you want.
Otherwise, yes you will have to write a fragment shader to process it.

Answer (score 0):

To create a drawing like this I would still suggest you to use the shaders but if not there are still plenty of ways to draw this but it will require you to do at least 2 draw calls.

So the best way to ask me is to draw all of these drawings only to alpha channel. That means only alpha will be drawn to while the colors will persist as they are. To do so you need to first clear the alpha to zero so when you clear color buffer make sure that the alpha component is set to zero `glClearColor(0,0,0,0)` should do. Now before you stop drawing use the color mask to enable only alpha: `glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE)`. Now draw your images using with `glBlendFuncSeparate( GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ONE)`. This means ignore the color of your texture (the RGB part of it) and use whatever color was on the buffer previously and it means use the alpha from the texture and sum it to whatever was already on the buffer (the last value makes more sense to be `GL_ZERO` but that would prevent overlapping). Now draw as many of such textures as you want. You might have only one but it should work for any number of them.

So at this point your buffer will have alpha zero everywhere but where you have drawn your textures and the textures had non-zero alpha. So it is time to draw the actual color. We need to reenable the color mask to draw to color so `glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE)` (the alpha part could be set to false but let us reset that one as well). Now to draw the actual color we need to overlay the parts that have alpha so let us setup the blending to `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO)` . This means we will apply color depending on the current alpha state on the buffer. If the state there is 1 then a full color will be applied, if alpha is 0 then the same color will stay as it is, if 0.5 it will mix the color that has previously been on the buffer with the new color which means that if you have a white background you might want to clear the color to `(1,1,1,0)`. The alpha then will be overridden to whatever the new alpha will be set to in the color.

Now either redraw a fullscreen rectangle with disabled textures and a color set to whatever the target color should be (the violet one) and you are all done. Or you can redraw a rectangle(s) only wherever the images were drawn.

Not easy enough? How about this:

- Set clear color to the color of your shapes `glClearColor(violet.r, violet.g, violet.b, 0.0)` Keep the alpha at zero
- Clear color buffer
- Set color mask to draw to alpha only `glColorMask(GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE)`
- Enable a most comon blend func `glBlend(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`
- Draw your textures as you would any other
- Reset the color mask to default `glColorMask(GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE, GL_TRUE)`

**Note:** This last procedure will only work if blending is enabled for your view/screen/canvas. If not then only the RGB part will be presented in most cases which will result for the whole screen to have a solid color.